# How to use ngStyle with :nth-child?

Tags: css, angular

I am new to Angular, and I am trying to style items after the 6th child but it doesn't work. I can color everything, but when I add the nth-child part it doesn't work. Do I have a wrong syntax?

**[ngStyle] = "div:nth-child(n+6){'background-color': 'red'}"**

```
<p *ngIf = "status"> Secret Password is Tuna</p> 
<div *ngFor="let clickLog of clickLogs" 
   [ngStyle]="div:nth-child(n+6){{'background-color': 'red'}}">
  {{clickLog}} 
</div>
<button (click)="clickEvent()">Show Details</button>
<button [disabled]="!checkIfEmty()" (click)="resetUserName()">Reser Username</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use a css selector inside an inline style definition. Quite a few other syntax issues also. Maybe re-teach yourself the fundamentals of html / css before attempting this.

Comment: The `ngStyle` directive applies the CSS styles to the element itself. You need to use the component style file (the CSS or SCSS) for this.

Comment: @31piy Thank you for  your answer. I have style file, but wanted to try styling with ngStyle.

Comment: Here is solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-num8ry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo class in the component CSS file.

**app.component.css**

```css
div:nth-child(n+6) {
  background-color: red
}
```

But you should have proper structure for it in template.

Or you can use index of `ngFor`.

**app.component.ts**

```html
<div *ngFor="let clickLog of clickLogs; index as i" 
   [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i >= 6 ? 'red' : '' }">
  {{clickLog}} 
</div>
```

Comment: I think there is error while complie `Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{'background-color': i >= 6 ? 'red' : '' }}]`